# VB.NET Unit Test with parameters

Tags: .net, vb.net, unit-testing, mstest

At my job, I often switch between developing on projects written in VB.NET and C#. I'm fairly new to Unit Testing and I've been researching and doing some tutorials on how to implement it, but everything I've been able to find has been written in C# (no vb.net examples). I use Visual Studio 2017, so I'm using msTest for Unit Testing.

For the most part I've been able to figure out the syntax differences between C# and vb.net unit testing with msTest, but there's one feature I can't seem to figure out in vb.net. In C# you can do this:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(1)]
[DataRow(2)]
[DataRow(3)]
public void unitTest(int n) {
    // Test code here
}
```

This allows you to run the same test for multiple values. I can't find the equivalent syntax for vb.net. Is there even a way to do this in vb.net?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Here is how my unit test class is setup and what I'm hoping to achieve:

```vb
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

<TextClass()> Public Class MyUnitTests

    <DataTestMethod()> _
    <DataRow(1)> _
    <DataRow(2)> _
    <DataRow(3)> _
    Public Sub IsValueLessThanTwo(ByVal n as Integer)
        Assert.IsTrue(n < 2, $"{n} is not less than 2")
    End Sub

End Class
```

I would expect this test to run 3 times and pass when the value is 1 but fail when the value is 2 or 3. If I convert this to C#, it runs as expected. But as is, when I build the project I get the following errors:

> Type 'DataTestMethod' is not defined.
>
> 'DataRow' cannot be used as an attribute because it does not inherit from 'System.Attribute'.

Comment: You are basically asking us to convert c# to VB.net?

Comment: No, I want to know if it is possible to do in VB.NET what I'm doing with the C# code above. Simply changing the square brackets to angle brackets doesn't work because VB.NET does not recognize <DataTestMethod> or <DataRow(n)> as valid attributes.

Comment: Because you are probably missing references.(Imports). It is just a matter of syntax. You can do the same thing in VB.net as you did in c#. Hence my previous statement. And the answer provided was based solely on the sparse information provided in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have included some of the code I'm trying to use. I just added it to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple services online that can be used to convert code.

For example

[Convert Code by Telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/)

```
<DataTestMethod> _
<DataRow(1)> _
<DataRow(2)> _
<DataRow(3)> _
Public Sub unitTest(n As Integer)
    ' Test code here
End Sub

'=======================================================
'Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
'Conversion powered by NRefactory.
'Twitter: @telerik
'Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
'=======================================================
```